# Replacement for Network Diagnostics in macOS?

Tags: macos, wifi

Network Diagnostics was removed from Mojave. The replacement does not tell you if the failure to connect issue is with the Internet, or your own WiFi. The program could often fix connections where the replacement can only give a report.

Is there a (3rd party) replacement for Network Diagnostics?

Comment: Have you tried copying over the app from High Sierra?

Comment: Yes. No joy, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There's been [no effort to remake that app by Apple](https://eclecticlight.co/2023/12/09/where-have-the-network-tools-gone/).

The first party tools (which ended on Catalina for Network Utility as well) are listed here:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-network-utility-on-mac-ntutl001/10.15/mac/10.15

Most of the data is now in the network preference pane and there is no full drop-in replacement for the old tool. We might need to just address each problem one by one and list specific tools that address each single problem you might have used the combined tool to address.

Third party options exist, like What Route.

- https://www.whatroute.net/

Comment: I don't see Network Diagnostics there at all. ND was a stand-alone tool that could tell you if the problem was with your computer, your network, your ISP or the Internet. No Mojave tool does this.

Comment: @user26732 I know ND. It’s gone, use NU and system prefs is my advice. No third party tool I know is good enough for me to recommend. When that changes, I’ll gladly edit my post to update it. The word most implies not all functions made the cut - you lose functionality.

Comment: @bmike In Big Sur, even Network Utility is just an alert to say it's been deprecated. (But it doesn't work at all, so it's more than just deprecation.)

Comment: My hunch (without reverse engineering the old app) @benwiggy was it didn't use the new network extensions and went into kernel space so it's not gonna have a full replacement by design. Also, networks aren't as flat now with secure DNS / DNS over https / all sorts of proxies and tunnels even from Apple as the first party. OP will need to adapt to new tools / methods to diagnose issues in all likelihood.